# debugging, constant reload

Tags: python, docker, flask

hello i would like to use debug inside container but i cannot add working "volumes" into docker comopse.xml

file structure in the piscture:

[image]

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine
WORKDIR /planner
ENV FLASK_APP=app
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

compose:

```
   version: "3.7"
    services:
      web:
        build: .
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "5000:5000"
        volumes:
          - .:/planner
    
      rq-dashboard:
        image: jaredv/rq-docker:0.0.2
        command: rq-dashboard -H rq-server
        ports:
          - 9181:9181
    
      rq-worker:
        image: jaredv/rq-docker:0.0.2
        command: rq worker -u redis://rq-server:6379 high normal low
        deploy:
          replicas: 3
    
      rq-server:
        image: redis:alpine
        ports:
          - 6379:6379
```

problem is with:

```
volumes:
  - .:/planner
```

[image]

could you help me with it?

Comment: Basically try: `- ./:/planner` but be careful as that will also mount the compose file in your container, may be better to have a specific sub directory for the `web` service's volume.

Comment: I used ./web and it builds up ;) but the client doesn't restart when I change something in my application. But I would like to achieve constant development with dubug= True. In run.py file, I have this flag, but the container is telling me that:

`code
web_1           |  * Serving Flask app "app"
web_1           |  * Environment: production
web_1           |    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
web_1           |    Use a production WSGI server instead.
web_1           |  * Debug mode: off`

Comment: Try setting `ENV FLASK_ENV=development` in the Dockerfile to enable the live reloader.

Comment: I had to grant permission in the docker application for shearing. After that every worked :) Thank you! :)